# Is it better to use a warning icon, error icon, or no icon at all for login problems in a mobile app?

Tags: icons, error-message

Is it better to use a warning icon, error icon, or no icon at all for login problems in a mobile app?

Problems that may happen:

- Invalid/Incorrect email
- Wrong mail/password
- Connection errors

Answer (score 2):

A warning icon technically means that you can proceed with whatever you are doing but with a high level of risk involved, that could possible lead to an error. So assuming how far the user can proceed in the app with Invalid/Incorrect email, Wrong mail/password or
Connection errors, you can choose to display an error or warning icon. So if your user can still use the app without logging in, then a warning icon would suffice. Having no icon at all would be misleading the user if they are trying to use certain features that require them being logged in.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends upon the UI and how you have designed it overall and the type of target users you have in mind. There are UIs that are more iconised and less texty but the audience/users part dictates a lot of the UI/UX choices we make, so you can base that around it.

One hint is that if your users are mobile/computer savvy and might have had a formidable amount of experience playing with apps then you may use recognizable icons but still there no hard rule for the latter either.

Comment: Welcome to SE :) Your answer is very vage and can't give any worth to the asker. "It depends" is a kind of blah. What is your message and recommendation for the asker? What is your call to action? Which of the three icons should be used in which of the three error states? And why is this your recommendation?  Why not answering the concrete problem for the stated use case (login)?